# enable wifi with elevated rights in Powershell (without entering credentials)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to enable and disable the wifi adapter without entering the administrator credentials.

I an logged as a user without administrator rights but I have the administrator password.
This is my script, but it's not working

```
$username = '.\Administrator'
$password = 'pass'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Credential $credential -ArgumentList '-command "$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Wireless%; $wmi.disable()'"
```

What i want to achieve is what this code does:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Wireless%'"
$wmi.disable()
```

How can be done this ?

@Edit
Or something similar in order to be able to disable and enable the WIFI

Answer (score 0):

```
$adminaccount = ".\Administrator"
$PASSWORD = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force
$UNPASSWORD = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $adminaccount,$PASSWORD
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Wireless%'"
$wmi.disable() -Credential $UNPASSWORD
```

This could possibly work, but I can't be certain as I'm using Linux at the moment and cannot test it. Assuming the disable() method is the command that requires authentication, and that it accepts arguments such as that, this may work.

Click [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b2aba3d5-666e-453d-892a-e4dafc4304b2/how-to-pass-credentials-in-getwmiobject-command-?forum=winserverpowershell) for where I got my details, it should work.

The other option is to hold shift and right click on your script with just the following in and clicking run as different user, then enter in the admin credentials.

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Wireless%'"
$wmi.disable()
```

This option would mean you would have to type the admin credentials in, but you wouldn't have to switch user to do it.

Another possible way would be do try a different command to disable the adapter:

```
Disable-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet 2"
```

This could be ran like the following:

```
$username = '.\Administrator'
$password = 'pass'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Credential $credential -ArgumentList '-command "Disable-NetAdapter -Name ‘Ethernet 2’"'
```

All you'd have to do is replace "Ethernet 2" with your adapter name.

Comment: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:5 char:16

Unexpected token 'Credential' in expression or statement.
At line:5 char:17

Unexpected token 'UNPASSWORD' in expression or statement.
At line:5 char:28

Comment: I was worried about that - perhaps try shifting the -Credential argument to the Get-WmiObject part: `$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Wireless%'" -Credential $UNPASSWORD'